# Can't ping Windows 7 from Android phone and vice versa in the same network, but other machines can

Tags: wi-fi, windows

I have an Android phone and a notebook running Windows 7, both are Wi-Fi enabled. Both devices are on the same network and they can't see each other (I can't ping phone from notebook and vice versa). But, to make it more weird, let me show you my network structure.

```
      Name  -       OS  -   IPv4 Address
----------------------------------------
    Router  -           -    192.168.1.1
ComputerXP  -    WinXP  -  192.168.1.103
ComputerW7  -     Win7  -  192.168.1.104
NotebookW7  -     Win7  -  192.168.1.106
 Telephone  - Android4  -  192.168.1.109
```

Now, `ComputerXP` and `ComputerW7` can ping all devices in given network. `NotebookW7` and `Telephone` can both ping `Router`, `ComputerXP` and `ComputerW7`. The only connection that does not work is `Notebook7 <--> Telephone`.

I have previously had this problem, I tried restarting `NotebookW7`, `Telephone` and `Router`, disabling and re-enabling Wi-Fi connection and firewall, pinging anywhere and nothing was working. Later on when my dad came home, I wanted to show him this situation, but suddenly I was able to connect to `NotebookW7` from my `Telephone` like magic. I was happy that the issue got fixed. I stopped using this connection for a while and now I wanted to establish it again and guess what, it's again not working. I have no idea what is going on.

I used ping on Windowss and [Ping & DNS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ulfdittmer.android.ping) on Android to test ping.

**EDIT 1**: For some reason, I was not able to ping `ComputerW7` using my `Telephone` for a while. So in my `Telephone` I started external software for managing files. I added new network place with IP Address of `ComputerW7` (192.168.1.104) and pressed test connection. It was doing something for a while and then it printed "Test successful". I went back to Ping & DNS, and re-pinged same IP Address and it started working for some reason. I did same thing with my `NotebookW7`, but I got "Test not successful" in my file manager.

**EDIT 2**: Little bit more weirdness. I added one more Android Phone (lets call it just `Phone`) to the network and checked all possible pings from outside to the `Phone`. Nothing worked. Then I tried to connect to VLC Player at `ComputerXP` using `Phone` and it worked. After that I was able to ping `Phone` from `ComputerXP`. Not really sure how this works. Only difference is that `Phone` has Android 4.2.2, but `Telephone` has 4.1.2.

**EDIT 3**: New thing I tried was to create Wi-Fi Router from `Telephone` and connecting to it using `NotebookW7`, it worked. However, I still was not able to ping it.

Comment: Good analysis so far (+1 for that). Though I have no real solution to your issue, something that might prove helpful is an [app for network diagnosis](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_diagnosis) (the link goes to a listing of relevant apps). Such an app might at least help you figure the phone → laptop part. Good luck!

Comment: @Izzy: I downloaded Fing app, and when I started it, it scanned network and found devices I can ping to (`Router`, `ComputerXP` and `ComputerW7`). However, I am not sure if this is the right app to perform this kind of diagnostics.

Comment: I have not used any of them either, was just providing a pointer I hoped proving helpful.

Comment: Android might not respond to pings in power-saving mode. Have you tried disabling WiFi sleep? Alternatively, have you tried pinging your computer from your phone?

Comment: @Huey Android phone was not in power-saving mode and even has WiFi sleep turned off. I tried pinging computer from phone and it didnt get any respond.

Comment: What's the IP address of `Phone`? Could there possibly be an IP conflict?

Comment: @Huey Not likely, every network machine has deffinitely unique address. It gets it from DHCP and there is no address (range) reserved for certain MACs.

Comment: On `Telephone`, does pinging `localhost` work?

Comment: Zereges hi check this out on windows 7 firewall and ip rules for ping
http://www.sysprobs.com/enable-ping-reply-windows-7
If this applies, killing and restarting your firewall without setting the rules for pinging would leave you where you started. A quote from the page "Reasons: By default ICMP echo requests, used for ping command is blocked in Windows 7 firewall default settings."

Comment: @moonbutt74 Ping was not the only protocol I tested. I mainly tested this because of VLC remote control.

Comment: Ok, if you are having network problems then install zanti, a network diagnosis tool which will let you connect to open ports to a machine on the same network. Test it and se if it connects via this and then will get some info about the problem.

Comment: @Hunter The problem with my problem is, that it sometimes work. For example now it is working in both directions, but who knows what will happen in few days.

Comment: Thats why asking to use zanti, as it will tell you many things about your network and drvices. If you have a laptop then just create a hotspot on your phone or laptop and connect it to the other device and then see if it pings or not.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a Samsung Android running Lolipop? It is actually locked down and some Chinese hackers actually created the PINGPONG root to enable pinging from a Samsung Android.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/general/root-pingpongroot-s6-root-tool-t3103016